# Highcharts offline export does not work after upgrading to highcharts 9.0.1 and highcharts-angular 3.0.0

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, web, highcharts

I am using highcharts and highcharts-angular in order to create a pdf with multiple graphs, using the offline exporting.
Previous to the upgrade to highcharts 9.0.1 I have been using highcharts 8.2 and highcharts-angular 2.4 and everything worked fine. After upgrade I keep encountering this error
[[image]]

My code looks like:

```
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import HC_exporting from "highcharts/modules/exporting";
import offlineExporting from "highcharts/modules/offline-exporting";
HC_exporting(Highcharts);
offlineExporting(Highcharts);
import { defaultSeriesColorsArray, defaultSpecialColorsArray, defaultSpecialColorsEnum } from '../../constants/colors.constants';
import { ChartModel, PieChartModel } from '../../models/chart.model';

export class ChartOptionsHelper {


    constructor() {
    }

    public static buildChart(options: Highcharts.Options): any {
        const chartDiv = document.createElement('div');
        const charAsSVG = Highcharts.chart(chartDiv, options).getSVG();
        return charAsSVG;
    }
}
```

So far I have tried moving the calls to HC_exporting and offlineExporting before the getSVG is being called, but the error persisted. The only way I managed to get rid of the error is by removing those 2 calls.

Is there a workaround or a fix for this issue? I have not seen any information about these methods being deprecated

Comment: Hi @Ciprian Nazarie, I've tried to debug the problem, but exporting seems to work correctly with Highcharts 9.0.1 and highcharts-angular 3.0.0. Could you reproduce the issue in some online code editor? You can start from: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-line-krktht?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek, Thank you for your reply. I have managed to figure out the issue after trying to reproduce in a smaller project. Apparently it is caused by the microfrontend architecture we have adopted. We are using highcharts only in the microfrontend project, but someone has added and shared it from the shell as well. After removing it from the parent the issue does not reproduce anymore.